# How to pass data from a non-activity class to an activity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm building my app and I'm using socket.io to communicate with a webserver. I have java files that take care of that which are not activities and run in the background. So to start them, it will be instantiated in an activity and the sockets will run. Now the webserver triggers messages which I handle in the callback and pass the data to an activity. Now I'm looking for the best way to pass data from a running non-activity class to an activity currently running.

What I did before was using an intent created by the non-activity class which sent the data to the currently running activity. The actvity had to be changed to singleinstance or singletop to avoid the activity from keeping on restarting on itself. 
The problem is that form my main actvity I can't use single top launchmode because I need the actvity to refresh on itself in some instances.

So I can't get the sockets properly working on the main activity because I can only recieve data if I change my main activity to singletop which is not ideal for the app. I had first tried nameing a function in the acivity that would be called by the non-activity class but it seems that, that's illegal, so I'm pretty stuck here.

```
@Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... data) {

        System.out.println("Server may have triggered event '" + event + "'");

        if (event.equals("message")) {
        System.out.println(data[2]);

        Intent newIntent = new Intent(Chat.mContent, Chat.class);
        Bundle extras=new Bundle();
        extras.putString("name", (String)data[1]);
        extras.putString("MSG", (String)data[2]);
        newIntent.putExtras(extras);


        Chat.mContent.startActivity(newIntent);

        }
        if (event.equals("ready")) {
            System.out.println("Received the ready callback");
            try{
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(TabExercise.mContext, TabExercise.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("ready", event);
            TabExercise.mContext.startActivity(newIntent);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Caught an error");
            }


        }
    }
```

This is the method in the non-activity class where the data is sent.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
super.onNewIntent(intent);
Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();

if (intent.hasExtra("ready")) {
    // Retrieve the message and call getMsg(String)
   connect.starter(SaveSharedPreference.getName(TabExercise.this), SaveSharedPreference.getUserId(TabExercise.this));

}
```

}

This is the where the intent is caught in the mainactivity. Not ideal.

Comment: Hmm I don't see how that will work, since it needs to work in real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you may find helpful is to use `Singletons` or perhaps a non-UI `Fragment`. If you aren't using Fragments already for your UI, you should definitely [look into it](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) because it is the de jure standard for modern android apps. What's more, the Android Support Library gives Fragments all the way back to Android 1.6 which is ideal for backwards compat.

You could equally pass data and messages around using `Handlers` between threads. These basically provide a pipeline which you can `post` messages to and `handleMessage`. You would probably start your network stuff in your `Application` `onCreate` and perhaps store the thread as a `singleton`. You would then pass a reference to your UI `Handler` to this thread which can then communicate directly to your UI by posting `Runnables`.

An interesting answer for which is 'better' can be found here:

[Non-UI Fragment vs Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577132/non-ui-fragment-vs-singleton)

Comment: To help you along, if you want to be communicating/listening in the background for the entire duration of your application (including between Activities), then you should be looking to extend the `Application` class and initialise your `singletons` there and then. The method to override is `onCreate` which is invoked once and only once when the application is *first* launched. However, if the process is killed by android (e.g. due to memory strain), it will be called again when the user navigates back.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I got your conception working irrespective of the launchmode and it simplifies my code dramatically.

Comment: I will still read more about fragments and handlers too though.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i understood the question, you start your activity, from there you start your CommunicationHandler instance?

then you'll let your activity implement any kind of CallBack interface, instantiate your Handler with the CallBack (means: the activity) and call the CallBacks call method.

see [this question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android) for some more details on how to use callbacks

sorry if i understood it wrong :-)

**edit:**

Your MainActivity (the one starting your SocketConnector and receiving the messages) should provide an implementation of a callback interface. the interface could look something like this:

```
public interface IMessageReceiver {
  public void onMessageReceived(Message m);
}
```

with your Message class looking like:

```
public class Message {
  String name;
  String msg;
  //add getter/setter and constructor to fit your needs
}
```

then your main activity should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IMessageReceiver {
  //... main activity code here.
    SocketConnector mySC = new SocketConnector(this);
  //... more main activity code here.
  public void onMessageReceived(Message m) {
    //do something with the message, e.g. display to edit texts, lists etc.
  }
}
```

and in your SocketConnector you will define the  IMessageReceiver as a final member and call the `receiver.onMessageReceived(m)` - should be like

```
IMessageReceiver receiver

public SocketConnector(IMessageReceiver receiver) {
  this.receiver = receiver;
}

@Override
public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... data) {
  if (event.equals("message")) {
      System.out.println(data[2]);

      //Intent newIntent = new Intent(Chat.mContent, Chat.class);
      //Bundle extras=new Bundle();
      //extras.putString("name", (String)data[1]);
      //extras.putString("MSG", (String)data[2]);
      //newIntent.putExtras(extras);


      //Chat.mContent.startActivity(newIntent);
      Message m = new Message();
      m.name = (String)data[0];
      m.msg = (String)data[1];
      this.receiver.onMessageReceived(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well not really. The actvity does start the communication handler which in turns starts the socketconnector and the callbackinterface. The callbacks are already handled and received, now the problem is how to get the values from the callback to the running activity.

Comment: did you declare your interface' call method with arguments? let me add some code for this

Comment: Yes. public void on(String event, JSONObject data); That's how the callback is setup in the interface.

Comment: the callback you declare is just for receiving the data between your socketConnector and the callbackinterface, not between your activity and the socketconnector. and no: declaring your activity singleton is not - nice.